# Excel vba fnd function missing part

Tags: excel, vba

I want to accomplish something that is probably quite simple but I am not able to find the documentation for this and the parameter i need.

This is within Excel.

I have this code attached to a button:

```
Sub Search_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Find What:="asdf", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").FindControl( _
    ID:=1849, recursive:=True).Execute
End Sub
```

This open the standard search function with "asdf" to search for. I want to set it to search within the whole workbook and then execute the search.

What could I add for this. I'm quite new to excel VB but i'm experienced with coding in general.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="asdf", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Will actually execute the `.Find()` command, it won't open the Find dialog box and wait for you to do something. As I'm reading your code, that would make the

```
Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").FindControl( _
   ID:=1849, recursive:=True).Execute
```

Line redundant

When `.Find()` executes, it returns a range pointing to what it found, so the usual call would be something like:

```
Dim rng as Range
set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="asdf", LookAt:=xlWhole)
if rng is nothing then
  'nothing found, handle that here
else
  'found it! process appropriately
end if
```

Comment: What I want to do i to actually open the Dialog box. Any way I can do this with some preset parameters?

My code above is working and the asdf if transfered over to the dialog box. Now, I want to set the option "Within" to "Workbook" and execute the search.

Comment: If your goal is to search the entire workbook, then this should do it:     `set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Find(What:="asdf", LookAt:=xlWhole)`. If your goal is to have the search dialog box open, it sounds like you've actually achieved that, and I'm not sure what else you're asking